# How to create a class that prints an array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to create this array ["name", age] and be able to print it using a class:

```js
let person: Person[] = [["Anne", 21], ["Coco", 33]];
class Person{
  person: Person[];
  printPerson(): person{
    for (let i of person) {
      document.write( i + '<br/>');
        }
}
```

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels, please read the basics for Typescript and Object-oriented programming first.

Comment: thanks, you are great, have a good...ammm nigth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will allow you to print general nested arrays (I haven't implemented it in a class but this would be easy to do):

```
let persons: (string | number)[][] = [["Anne", 21], ["Coco", 33]];

const printArray = (array: any[]) => {
    for (const element of array) {
        if (element instanceof Array) {
            printArray(element);
        } else {
             document.write(element.toString() + '<br/>');
        }
    }
}

printArray(persons);
```

Output:

```
Anne
21
Coco
33
```

However, since you are expecting the inner arrays to have the same shape I would recommend implementing them with a Typescript class. The code below defines a `Person` class with its own `write` method, creates an array of `Persons`, and then iterates over each one and calls its `write` method:

```
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;

    print = () => {
        document.write(this.name + ' is ' + this.age + '<br/>');
   };

    constructor(name: string, age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

let persons: Person[] = [
    new Person("Anne", 21),
    new Person("Coco", 33)
];

for (let p of persons) {
    p.print();
}
```

Output:

```
Anne is 21
Coco is 33
```